# Marking a comment as resolved?

Tags: feature-request, comment

### The problem

Sometimes someone comments on a question suggesting that some aspect of the question be clarified or otherwise changed. Then the OP changes the question accordingly, sometimes including some text in the question to indicate where the edit was made, and sometimes adding a comment of their own to say that they have responded to the initial comment. If the clarification is successful, we now have possibly 1-2 unnecessary comments and possibly some unnecessary text in the question describing changes relative to the original. Maybe these things were useful in order for the initial commenter to see the change, but eventually, they likely become unnecessary. Unnecessary text is bad because it wastes future readers time.

### How to deal with the problem?

Is there a standard approach to dealing with this? Should these extra comments be deleted? Could there be a button to mark as resolved? There could be a button for the OP to suggest that the initial commenter's comment be marked as resolved and then the latter person could accept or reject. Then, if accepted, the comments would be hidden but possibly available after clicking a show hidden comments" button.

Comment: Two minor comments: the flag dialog for comments has a "no longer needed" option which would be relevant to some of these concerns, and sometimes the history of the changes in the question can be helpful in crafting an answer that more fully addresses the asker's underlying issues.